# Is there a way to combine all elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm making a website, and I want to string together all the items in an array.
e.g:

```
function combineArray {
const myArray = [text1, text2, text3];
//code to output text1text2text3 here
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: A possible solution would be to use `Array.prototype.join()` (Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`join` will join all elements in the array with the specified delimiter (use
empty string `''` since the default separator is comma `,`)

```js
const myArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
const res = myArray.join('');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `toString()` is redundant, it's already a string.

Comment: Modified, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join('')` to achieve what you are looking for.

```js
const myArray = ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
const combineArray = myArray.join('');
console.log(combineArray);
```

documentation for [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Think about using `join('')`.

Comment: Thanks didn't know that, updated my answer